# Android - Convert a date to the date format of the device

Tags: android, date-formatting

How do you convert a date to the date format of the device? For example, I have following date: 02/11/2011 (mm/dd/yyyy). How to convert it to the format of the device?

Comment: What do you mean by  `format data of device` ???

Comment: The format data of device should be dd/mm/yyyy or yyyy/mm/dd, I want to convert my data (mm/dd/yyyy) to the format data of device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert a Date into required format.

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details..

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String formattedDate = format.format(yourdate);
```

Comment: I don't know the required format, I need to convert my date (mm/dd/yyyy) to the device's current time format.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider storing your dates in a more locale-agnostic way as milliseconds.

Then you can use `DateFormat.getDateFormat()` like this:

```
dateTextView.setText(DateFormat.getDateFormat(getActivity()).format(new Date(millis)));
```

According to the documentation for `getDateFormat()`:

> Returns a DateFormat object that can format the date in short form (such as 12/31/1999) according to the current locale and the user's date-order preference.

Answer (score 1):

`DateFormat` has the static methods `getDateTimeInstance`, `getTimeInstance` and `getDateInstance` that are already localized